# is there any way to give multiple value in duration svg animation tag?

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters, svg-animate

i am trying to perform some animation operation on svg but i am not able to get the outcome i want is there any way to add morethen one value on

```
<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="visibility" from="hidden"  to="hidden" values="hidden;visible;hidden" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

i am giving multiple values in values="..." but is there any possible way to do same with dur i want every values in diffrent time span can anyone guide me in right direction?

Comment: i want to give custom duratom for every value For ex 3 values is there so i want 1st value to take 0.8s 2nd value to take 1.2 s and 3rd one should take 0.1s

Comment: it worked can you put it as answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use values and keyTimes.

e.g.

```
<animate attributeType="CSS" attributeName="visibility" values="hidden;visible;hidden" keyTimes="0;0.4;0.6" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```